# LINQ grp.Max(...) not giving just max value

Tags: c#, linq

I am working with LINQ \ EF and I am trying to replace a SQL Stored Proc using Dapper with Entity Framework.

I am 99% there with a particular aspect of the call, however I am getting 2 too many results because the select is not getting just the max value.

The SQL

```
SELECT
    MAX(QS.QSVersion) AS LatestVersion,
    QS.QSNo           AS VerQSno
FROM
    [forms].QS
INNER JOIN
    [forms].QSCollectionMappings qsc
        ON qsc.QSNo = QS.QSNo
WHERE
    qsc.QSCollectionTypeId = @QSCollectionTypeId
    AND QS.StatusId = 2
GROUP BY
    QS.QSNo;
```

The LINQ

```
ar join = (from qs in QS
            join qscm in QSCollectionMappings on 
                    new { QuestionNumber = qs.QSNo, Version = qs.QSVersion } equals 
                    new {QuestionNumber = qscm.QSNo, Version = qscm.QS.QSVersion} 
            where qscm.QSCollectionTypeId == collectionId && qs.StatusId == 2
            group qs by new
            {
                QuestionNumber = qs.QSNo,
                QuestionVersion = qs.QSVersion,

            } into grp
            select new {
                QuestionNumber = grp.Key.QuestionNumber,
                QuestionVersion = grp.Max(x => x.QSVersion)
            });
```

The results

```
 The results 

     QSNo   |Version

|34 |-| 1.0 |
|38 |-| 1.0 |  // Should not show
|276|-| 1.0 |  // Should not show
|38 |-| 2.0 |
|276|-| 2.0 |
```

I would be grateful if I could be advised on what I have done wrong here so that I can fix the issue.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: show us your SQL query as well

Comment: You're grouping on the Question Number and the Version.  If you just want the max Version then remove it from the key you group by.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic edited the question

Comment: @juharr when trying that I cant access the other required properties I need to work with

Comment: All you need is the Question Number (which will be the Key) and the Version, so exactly what will you not have access to?  Note I'm not talking about changing the FK you use to join the tables, just what you use to group the results on.

Comment: removing qs.QSNo from the group by gives me this `'<anonymous type: decimal QuestionVersion>' does not contain a definition for 'QuestionNumber' and no extension method 'QuestionNumber' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: decimal QuestionVersion>'

Comment: You need to group by the QSNo without using an anonymous object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by both the `QSNo` and the `QSVersion`, technically, each unique combination will be on a seperate group, which means the results are correct.

What you should do instead is to group on the `QSNo` alone, and then use `Max` on the versions.

I can't test the code, but this snippet should work:

```cs
    var join = (from qs in QS
        join qscm in QSCollectionMappings on 
                new { QuestionNumber = qs.QSNo, Version = qs.QSVersion } equals 
                new {QuestionNumber = qscm.QSNo, Version = qscm.QS.QSVersion} 
        where qscm.QSCollectionTypeId == 3 && qs.StatusId == 2
        group qs by qs.QSNo into grp
        select new {
            QuestionNumber = grp.Key,
            QuestionVersion = grp.Max(p => p.QSVersion)
        });
```

Comment: I didnt think that this was right, but then i cant access the other properties if I dont group by both

Comment: `QSNo` will become the Key, and the versions will become the values inside the group, so you'll simply do `grp.Max()` (can't test the code).

Comment: You should probably actually show the code changes in your answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks! spot on. I can see where I was going wrong now